# Add or remove widget on runtime

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I would like to know whether it´s possible to add or remove specified widgets on runtime.

form example i press any tool on my toolbar and add widget to sidebar .
press again to remove widget.

Answer (score 1):

Adding widgets is not difficult. you can use [`topic.publish('viewer/loadWidget')`](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/blob/master/viewer/js/viewer/Controller.js#L77)

Removing them can be more problematic - depends on the widget and whether it properly cleans up after itself. ;)

I have accomplished the same thing by loading all the widgets at the start and showing/hiding the desired widget using css. Roughly something like this :

`domStyle.set(dom.byId('find_parent'), 'display', 'block');`

`domStyle.set(dom.byId('find_parent'), 'display', 'none');`

In this case `find_parent` is the id for the titlePane widget that contains the CMV Find widget. Note that I don't usually use `dom.byId` for this. It is a simple example of one option.

Would this approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

thanks dear tmcgee. this work for me.

```
  <script>
        require(["dojo/dom-style", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (style, dom, on) {
            on(dom.byId("btnidentify"), "click", function () {
                var p_identify = dom.byId("identify_parent");
                if (p_identify.style.display === 'none') {
                    p_identify.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    p_identify.style.display = 'none';
                }

            });
        });
</script>
```